# Acumatica - Error running REST API calls back to back

Tags: c#, rest, asynchronous, acumatica

When I attempt to load Cases and related Activities into Acumatica, the following error occurs intermittently on the PUT calls:

```
PX.Data.PXException: Error: 'Summary' cannot be empty.
PX.Data.PXOuterException: Error: Inserting  'Activity' record raised at least one error.
Please review the errors.`
```

I can see that the Summary field is filled in correctly in my json string.  If I add a delay in the PUT method with either `Thread.Sleep(250)` or `Task.Delay(250)` (if using async), the error does not occur, but the processing is of course slower.  Is there a reason why the above error occurs as I load the data, and disappears if I add the delay?

I was using async/await but removed them all to see if that helped.  It did not resolve the issue.  Adding the delay to resolve the issue makes me think it has something to do with the application sending too many calls to Acumatica at once.  I thought the REST API could push a lot of data in very quickly.  Am I mistaken?

This is my current PUT call without async:

```
private T PutData<T>(string url, T bodyContent)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
    try
    {
        string jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyContent);
        HttpResponseMessage response = _httpClient.PutAsync(
            url, new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Logger.Error(string.Format(
                "Put call failed for {0}\r\n{1}\r\n{2}",
                bodyContent.GetType().Name,
                jsonContent,
                response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result));
            return default(T);
        }

        string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex, "PutData failed\r\n" + ex.Message);
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure Summary is not empty when you are getting the errors ?

Comment: Yes, Summary is loaded correctly each time.  I output the json string along with the error, so I can see that it is clearly entered.  That is what makes the error odd to me.  I also have another SO question for a related issue, and that issue is also giving me the same error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45630222/add-activity-attachment-through-rest-api